# React native self signed certification to a private server in an internal network

Tags: react-native, ssl

I am developing an app and it's main requirement is that it connects to a ssl server that is hosted on a linux machine in an internal network that has no domain name. The app is bundled with it's own device and own server. I have found that the default react native config doesn't allow self signed certs unless I ship it with the application somehow.

How do I go about have a two way ssl connection between a node.js express server and a react native app?

I have tried creating a .der file and adding it as a trusted CA file on the mobile device but that hasn't worked and introduced another problem by forcing the tablet to have a lock screen pin. So that's not an option.

I can't have a trusted or valid ssl Cert because the server will never have a domain name...

So that leaves me with self signed certs, but I can't find any resource explaining how to properly get react native to trust a self signed cert.

Comment: "the server will never have a domain name" why? Register any domain name, like `example.com` and then use it as suffix for any of your own internal naming needs. You can generate certificates for it as long as you control the DNS or the HTTP part of it, so even internal hosts could get certificates, if you use the DNS way to validate names.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Because the server never has external internet access. The app is meant to connect to that server, and the server connects to another internal server that handles data collection. Basically the server is a data collection server that then sends the data to a master server.

Comment: "Because the server never has external internet access." which is completely irrelevant to both having a name and even an x.509 certificate, as I explained if you control the DNS.

Comment: sorry my bad, I should clarify that im not that knowledgeable in this kind of back end. We don't control the DNS, we are developing this app /server combo for a client. We basically have a master server that gets connections from the data collection servers. Our data collection servers connect to our master server via ip address only. We have multiple DC servers therefore we can't really register many domains just for those servers. if that makes any sense?